# one-parameter subgroup of a one-dimensional connected Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group of dimension one and let $U=\{u_t\}_{t \in \mathbb R }$ be a one-parameter subgroup. I wonder if it is true that $U=G$?

It is easy to see that $U$ is closed. So by a theorem in Lie theory, $U$ is a Lie subgroup. $U$ is not discrete and thus it must have dimension one. But I don't know how to go further

Comment: Up to isomorphism there are only two Lie groups of dimension $1$, and you can compute the one-parameter subgroups of both them explicitly. (In fact, one of the two groups is the universal covering group of the other, so you really only need to compute for one of them.)

Comment: Correction : two **connected** Lie groups of dim 1: the  circle and the line.

Comment: What are those two types of lie groups explicitly?

Comment: The two groups are $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (circle) and $\mathbb{R}$ (line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\dim U=\dim G$, $U$ is open in $G$, and thus clopen.  Since $G$ is connected, this implies $U=G$.

Comment: Can you explain the first sentence?